# Application Not shown in itunesConnect

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

After I uploaded the application from Xcode it shows as successful. See image:

[image]

And I clicked on TestFlight tab and found it as the below image

[image]

After I clicked on App Store tab I didn't found it. I went back to TestFlight and I didn't find the build any more and it is still not showing. I spent almost 2 hours.

Any recommendation about this issue?

Comment: You have to wait for Apple to send you the email telling you the processing is complete.

Comment: It takes some time to processing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for the build to complete processing. It can take a couple of hours.

You should get an email when it is done and you will then be able to see it.